# PHP array to javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Suppose, I have this array in php

```
$cities=array(
    "Caracas"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4","3-5 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "18","3-5 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Los Teques"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4","3-5 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "18","3-5 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "La Victoria"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4","3-5 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "18","3-5 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Maracay"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4","3-5 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "18","3-5 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Tejeria"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4","3-5 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "18","3-5 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "La Encrucijada"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4","3-5 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "18","3-5 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Cagua"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4","3-5 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "18","3-5 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Turmero"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4","3-5 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "18","3-5 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "San Mateo"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4","3-5 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "18","3-5 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Margarita"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4","3-5 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "18","3-5 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Valencia"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4","3-5 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "18","3-5 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),

    // another section

    "Puerto la Cruz"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4.50","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "19","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Lecheria"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4.50","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "19","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Bacelona"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4.50","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "19","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Guanta"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4.50","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "19","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Puerto Piritu"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "4.50","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "19","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),

    // another section

    "Cumana"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "5.50","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "19.50","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Anaco"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "5.50","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "19.50","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Cantaura"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "5.50","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "19.50","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "El Tigre"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "5.50","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "19.50","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),

    // another section

    "Maturin"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "6","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "20","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Punta de Mata"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "6","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "20","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Ciudad Bolivar"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "6","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "20","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Puerto Ordaz"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "6","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "20","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),
    "Carupano"=>array(
        "air"=>array(
            "6","5-10 Working Days","Saturday"
        ),
        "sea"=>array(
            "20","4-6 Days","Wednesday"
        )
    ),

);
```

How can I convert that to javascript with every keys same? I want the same array in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>var cities = <?php echo json_encode($cities); ?>;</script>
```

then to access the data

```
<script>
  cities['San Mateo']['Air'][0]; // 4
  cities['San Mateo']['Air'][1]; // 3-5 Working Days
  // etc

  // looping
  for( var key in cities) {
    // key = city name
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode). JSON is the first, best, and only answer for php<->javascript data transfers.

Comment: How is the values accessible?

Comment: exactly the same as any other javascript data structure. `arr['Caracas']['air']`

Comment: Please do that and show the code to do. Please show me how to access the $cities['Caracas']['air'][0] using javascript and json

Comment: That's core/basic javascript, and work exactly the same as in PHP. You know how to do it in PHP, so you know how to do it in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert the array to JSON:

```
echo json_encode($cities);
exit;
```

Comment: Please do that and show the code to do. Please show me how to access the $cities['Caracas']['air'][0] using javascript and json

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
echo json_encode($cities);
```

jQuery

```
$.getJSON("php_file.php",function(data) {
    // "data" is the echoed encoded array from the php file.

    // "array"."city name"."'air' or 'sea'"."number value that is in the PHP file"
    data.Caracas.air.4 // this is how you access the data inside the array
});
```