# How to Detect Image snapped from which camera in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to detect the photograph from which camera it is snapped ? I have opened image file into notepad , i can see the camera name but how i can extract that name ? any idea . I wanted to in PHP ... ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [exif_read_data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) function. You will probably get the camera model, focal length, shutter speed and much more details.

Comment: Thanks Marc B & Vivek , Do you have any example ? It would be great to understand me !

Comment: I have tried, there no Camera name and shutter speed and all test1.jpg:
No header data found.
test2.jpg:
FILE.FileName: test2.jpg
FILE.FileDateTime: 1017666176
FILE.FileSize: 1240
FILE.FileType: 2
FILE.SectionsFound: ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, COMMENT
COMPUTED.html: width="1" height="1"
COMPUTED.Height: 1
COMPUTED.Width: 1
COMPUTED.IsColor: 1
COMPUTED.ByteOrderMotorola: 1
COMPUTED.UserComment: Exif test image.

COMMENT.2: Comment #3end
THUMBNAIL.JPEGInterchangeFormat: 134
THUMBNAIL.Thumbnail.Height: 1
THUMBNAIL.Thumbnail.Height: 1

Comment: The EXIF header is usually created by the image capturing device. This data might get removed if the image is edited or compressed. Try using an original image taken using a digital camera.

Comment: okay thanks , i will check it out ! can you give me your Email address ??? please

Answer (score 5):

Try the [EXIF](http://php.net/exif) functions. That's the standard method of storing such information in digital photos.

Comment: Fast answer @Mark.  Keep it up and 100K will come tonight.

Comment: That'd be a nice way to wrap up my 1 day holiday. back to the grind tomorrow.

Comment: BOOM!  Achievement unlocked: 100k displayed!

Comment: was it just me randomly up voting his past answers to see the 100k?

Comment: if the vote history is to be believed, the last 10pts came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839703/php-array-to-javascript-array/11839723#11839723   Either way. phew. helluva ride.

Comment: yup that was one of them :-), now to undo it all - bahahahahahaahaha