# php array to javascript array format

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

php array：

```
Array([0] => http://XXX/xgsyw/content/Uploads/Img/1111.jpg[1] => http://XXX/xgsyw/content/Uploads/Img/222.jpg)
```

to javascript "images"

```
$('#top').bgStretcher({
        images: ['images/sample-1.jpg', 'images/sample-2.jpg', 'images/sample-3.jpg', 'images/sample-4.jpg', 'images/sample-5.jpg', 'images/sample-6.jpg'],
        slideDirection: 'N',
        slideShowSpeed: 1000,
        transitionEffect: 'fade',
        sequenceMode: 'normal',
    });
```

Comment: And your question might be? (No, we won't write code for you unless you show your efforts.)

Comment: do i get bounty for guessing question?

Comment: Just a hint: `json_encode()`.

Comment: And seriously next time **USE GOOGLE OR STACKOVERFLOW SEARCH FIRST!!!** If you had exactly typed in your title, you would have gotten your answer as the first search result. http://bit.ly/1dUJ6vl

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP array to javascript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839703/php-array-to-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode it with the `JSON` library. Send it back to the Javascript, decode it, and append new `img` child nodes to some container.

```
echo json_encode(arrayOfImages);
```

Then in your JS:

```
var images = JSON.decode(returnValue);

images.each(function(path) {
   var img = $('<img>');
   img.attr('src', returnValue);
   img.appendTo('#imagediv');
});
```

**As noted in the comments..**

It is quicker to use `$(document.createElement("img"));` than to use the aforementioned suggestion.

Comment: This would be faster `var img = $( document.createElement("img") );`, the native variant is quicker than jQuery's

Comment: Edited into question. Thanks.

Comment: oh thanks but I didn't know how to do

Answer (score 1):

You might have done some more research online, because what you need for your solution is the `JavaScript Object Notation` short JSON.

Use `json_encode($your_array);`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

Comment: The results of"[\"http:\\/\\/localhost\\/xgsyw\\/content\\/Uploads\\/Img\\/1111.jpg\",\"http:\\/\\/localhost\\/xgsyw\\/content\\/Uploads\\/Img\\/222.jpg\"]"

Comment: Cannot be used in javascript

Comment: Parameter 2 has a escape function, I suggest you find the documentation in php.net :)

Comment: Yes, I saw, but will go wrong  “json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given”  My code “echo json_encode($array,JSON_HEX_TAG);”

Comment: As you can also find on php.net, the options are only available on php 5.3 or higher. Please check your php version.

Comment: @Jack_Yang and what are those two picture urls? If you meant for me to look at them, upload them somewhere else then **localhost**

Comment: They are native code,my php 5.2

Comment: Native code? That's what you write in your php file? or do you mean the actual return by the php script? How did you get all those backslashes in there?

Comment: json_encode($array,JSON_HEX_TAG);  return [\"http:\\/\\/localhost\\/xgsyw\\/content\\/Uploads\\/Img\\/1111.jpg\",\"http:\\/\\/lo‌​calhost\\/xgsyw\\/content\\/Uploads\\/Img\\/222.jpg\"]